# Super sensitive touchpad moved a folder into another folder, how do I find out what moved?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lxde

I'm on lubuntu and I accidentally moved a folder into another folder in my home folder. It happened in half a second while brushing against the touchpad. How do I find out what file moved where?

Comment: Right click and look for an undo option, Ctrl+z should do it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command

```
find /pth/to/dir -type f -mmin -60
```

will show you all files inside `/path/to/dir` and all of its subdirectories which have been modified in the last `60` minutes.

If you want to search for something less recent,

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -mtime -2
```

will displayed the files modified in the last 2 days.

The command

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -mtime -5 ! -mtime -2
```

will display files modified in the last 5 days, execpt for those modified in the last two days.

The command

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -mtime -5 -exec ls -al {} \;
```

will find files modified within the last five days, and will do an  ls of them, showing may useful properties.

Comment: When a directory (tree) is moved, is only the directory's modified date changed, or any subdirs or files too? Would "-type f" find it, or "-type d"?

Comment: @Xen2050 Let's say I create the file `/dir1/dir2/file`. `dir1` would not be modified, `dir2` would be. But in the OP two directories are modified, the one of origin and the destination one; while only one file is modified, the other one is deleted. So, searching for modified directories would find two such objects, searching for files only one.